# Jumblar: Using map locations as passwords

Tags: cryptanalysis, passwords

I had the idea of converting map locations into passwords. Basically Jumblar (github.com/micheal-swiggs/jumblar) takes a hash of the user's location and stores this as a comment on the PGP network. The 'stored-hash'(*Vague-Hash*) currently is only 2-bytes long. Each time the user wishes to use that location to generate passwords, they will first attempt supply a guess location. Jumblar then spirals around this guess location until it finds the point with the same hash.

Jumblar then uses this location as the basis for password generation. The user will add a 'spice' e.g username@email.com that Jumblar will use to generate a password. So rather than the user remembering a map location for each password, they only need to remember one location and a list of spices. Currently I'm assuming that is fine to store the spice(s) in open storage. So long as the map location remains a secret, the passwords derived from the spice(s) are 'safe'.

When Jumblar (github.com/micheal-swiggs/jumblar) generates a password there is a guarantee that it will contain atleast - one lowercase, one uppercase and one numeric - character.

**Vague Hash**

Jumblar only does a vague-hash of the secret location. Rather than storing the entire location hash on the PGP network, Jumblar only stores between 2-3 bytes of hash material. So a potential cracker could only discover a set of possible points that correspond to the vague-hash. The vague-hash is only used to distinguish the secret location from immediately surrounding locations. If the user guesses a location far away from the actual location, then Jumblar is likely to match an incorrect location.

A review and/or comments of the 'idea' and even the project would be greatly appreciated.

**Salt & Master Password**

The user must also remember a 'master' password and a salt accompanies each vague-hash. So the vague-hash is a result of hashing upon the secret location, password and salt.

Comment: The entropy contained in a single location is pretty low, so the generated password might be weak.

Comment: Especially with the hash of the location being available (stored as a comment on the PGP network, see first sentence), exhaustive search of the location is going to be quite easy (do the search spiraling away from the user's home for improved efficiency). Once you have that, guess the "spice" and recover the password.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that the stored hash is only 2-bytes long. So an attacker would only know a set of suitable locations. The intention of the stored hash is to only store enough information to distinguish the 'secret location' from surrounding locations.

Comment: Your "vague hash" should be replaced with a [secure sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_extractor#Secure_sketch). $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer Thanks, the implementation of the 'vague hash' is first two bytes of the SCrypt derivation function. This would qualify as a secure sketch?

Comment: How many possible locations are there, and how many pairs of them are adjacent to each other?

Comment: @RickyDemer Currently, Jumblar takes a location to be the latitude and longitude to 6 decimal places. So only using the decimal places then this gives 1,000,000 x 1,000,000 (10^12) locations. I don't quite know what you mean by "how many pairs of them are adjacent to each other"?

Comment: What I mean is "How many pairs of distinct locations are such that the intersection of their boundaries has positive length"? $\:$ (I can figure that out from what you said.) $\:$ "Vague hash" is incredibly unlikely to be a secure sketch, since scrypt is supposed to act "randomly". $\;\;\;$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9708/discussion-between-kurent-and-ricky-demer)

Comment: I don't know. If I don't know the location then I'm not that likely to remember it. If I do choose a known location then there is a big chance that an attacker would guess the right location. Many people are really bad at reading maps too. Seems to me that this is only good for thwarting attacks from geographically challenged attackers.

Comment: @owlstead I believe that the number of 'common' points would much be larger than the number of 'common' passwords. I believe that people are bad at reading maps when they navigate. However in a static setting people can quickly move around maps and find map features. Our minds are designed to quickly process visual information.

Comment: @Kurent Here's something from a user perspective: if I have to scroll a map for even 10 seconds then I'm reluctant to use your service. Entering a password takes < 1 second. Furthermore, a password does give me the __option__ to create a [strong password](https://xkcd.com/936/) against an attacker - your map idea does not. And let's put your keyspace into perspective, Wikipedia says the surface of the earth is $361132 \times 10^6 km^2$. If we'd mark every 10 square meter as a different password that's still only $361132 \times 10^{10} \approx 2^{51}$ different hashes - easy to bruteforce.

Comment: @nightcracker Thanks for your analysis, much appreciated. I do agree that the user scrolling the map could be an issue. I'm a bit undecided wrt strong password as you mentioned versus finding a map point. Also what number of hashes should there be? I'm thinking of adding the option for two map points.

Comment: @Kurent How many hashes there should be is a bit of a ballpark estimate and depends on the application/attacker you are facing. $2^{80}$ and above should be relatively safe though. But please allow me to warn you even further about this idea. $2^{51}$ might seem large, especially squared (two points), but most of that area is not going to be used by users. Users need to be able to find the location, so they're not going to pick a random location in the ocean. In fact, I think dictionary attacks with famous places and addresses freely available might be extremely successful against this idea.

Comment: @nightcracker In order for a dictionary attack to succeed this would require the attacker obtain the full hash of the secret location & password. This would be on a user's device. Such access would break most systems. The alternative is if an attacker obtained a hash of a derived password. Jumblar protects the full hash by running it through SCrypt prior to deriving passwords. My understanding is that by choosing suitable SCrypt parameters the 'full hash' is somewhat protected.